# implicit loading of a third part dll library

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to integrate in a pre-existing code a third part library which have been given to me with three files (.dll, .lib and .exe) plus a header file .h .

I tried the following steps:
- include the header file adding also the directory in the include directories
- add the library .lib to the linker inputs additional dependancy 
- move everything to the same folder of the solution

I'm using visual studio 2017. and all the code seems to compile with no errors, but when I try to access the functions of this library I got a message saying definition not found. Unfortunately I would like to access them to use only part of code that I need not the entire function. 
Do I forget something / have to do something else?

Comment: Could you include the exact message please.

Comment: It's not possible to access part of the code from a dll function (if I've understood the question correctly). The header file exposes the available dll functions and you choose which ones you call. It is likely that there is also an opaque type (the full class/struct implementation is not in the header file). This means you will need a forward declaration in the file which uses the dll functions.

Comment: "...not the entire function" Am I missing something here? How would you call part of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps for integration third-party dynamic libraries with VC++:

1) Change project configuration linker settings to dynamic runtime ( /MD )

2) Confirm platform of the third party (x86 / x64) and set accordingly in the vc++ project.

3) Include the header files. No compilation errors means that the header files are correctly included by the compiler.

4) Include the *.lib with path in the additional libraries; once correctly set, the project will build  successfully. Failing this step will give you - 'symbol not found', 'definition not found', and linker errors

5) Copy dll files to your application folder, failing which the .exe will not launch.  The dll files also has to conform to x86/x64 the project architecture/